# How can I choose the Zoom virtual background feature using Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, desktop-background, zoom-meeting

I have installed the Zoom Desktop Client for Linux on Ubuntu 18.04.
I would like to use the Virtual Background feature, but I do not know how to activate it.

My Zoom Linux Client Version is 3.5.385850.0413 and my laptop also meet the processor requirements (Dual Core 2Ghz or Higher (i5/i7 or AMD equivalent) processor)
[Virtual Background – Zoom Help Center](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/210707503-Virtual-Background)

Edit for clarification: I know this Zoom feature only works on Linux with a physical green screen. At the moment I do not get any message that I should put a green scree, I do not have that option at all. So even having a green screen I would not be able to use this feature.

Comment: sergiouribe's answer is correct, but i would add that for some reason launching zoom from the web *gives you less options* even if you are logged into your zoom account when you launched your meeting. the profile tab and 1 or 2 others also go missing. i think what is happening is that the credentials are not being completely or correctly transferred to the desktop app. if you launched from the web, you have to leave the meeting or sign out, then while still in the desktop app, explicitly log in to your account from the sign in dialog. you can also launch the desktop app directly and then sign

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://github.com/fangfufu/Linux-Fake-Background-Webcam - this seems to be a newer, maintained version, based originally on the same code as pangyuteng's answer, but updated to use more efficient libraries now.

Answer (score 34):

### **Edit: Zoom 5.8.0 supports virtual background without greenscreen!**

As of writing this, Zoom does not support person/face-detection based virtual background in their Linux-version software.  The solution below helps achieve the similar effect, and since it creates a virtual webcam, you can most likely use this solution for any apps that use a webcam, for example, Microsoft Teams.  These instructions were originally posted by @BenTheElder, and IMO is a super fun and neat project, especially if you are into computer vision.
https://elder.dev/posts/open-source-virtual-background/

What the code is doing essentially is grabbing image frames with Python and OpenCV.  For each image, the face/body is cropped using `TensorFlow.js Bodypix`, and merged with the specified background. The modified images are then used to create the video feed via `pyfakewebcam` and `v4l2loopback`.  I have tested the below instructions with Ubuntu 20.04, code used is archived in https://github.com/pangyuteng/virtual-background

branch `master` requires GPU, while branch `cpu-friendly` uses only CPU.

EDIT: after getting the below to work, I also found out there is a more refined version by fangfufu https://github.com/fangfufu/Linux-Fake-Background-Webcam which is also based on @BenTheElder's solution.

--

- install docker (https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu)
- (for those using GPU) install nvidia-docker (https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker)
- (for those using GPU) test nvidia-docker is installed properly

```
docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda:10.0-base nvidia-smi
```

- install and setup virtual video device as "/dev/video20", and assuming the actual video device is "/dev/video0"

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install -y v4l2loopback-dkms v4l2loopback-utils

sudo modprobe -r v4l2loopback
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1 video_nr=20 card_label="v4l2loopback" exclusive_caps=1
```

- add root to group video (likely unecessary...)

```
sudo usermod -aG video root
cat /etc/group | grep video
```

- clone repo

```
git clone git@github.com:pangyuteng/virtual-background.git vbkgd
cd vbkgd
```

- (for those using CPU) switch branch.

```
git checkout cpu-friendly
```

- build containers

```
docker-compose build
```

- (optional) adjust camera resolution and fps in `docker-compose.yml`
- start the virtual camera via docker-compose (assuming physical video device at `/dev/video0`, virtual video device at `/dev/video20` and gpu at `/dev/nvidia0`)

```
docker-compose up
```

- launch zoom/teams/slack..., select `v4l2loopback` as webcam
- live swap background by replacing file `data/background.jpg` - refresh rate hard coded at 3 seconds.

Comment: bodypix just died for me (Ubuntu 20.04) with a segfault. how do i go abt debugging  it?

Comment: @redDevil i initially want to say it could be memory issue, but if you have a modern gpu, likely bodypix would not crash due to out of memory error (RAM or GPU Ram). Maybe try rebooting, and feeding in bodypix one frame at a time to see if the bodypix container is functioning as expected.

Comment: i have an nvidia geforce gt 710.
This, however, worked fine in my other system with intel integrated graphics and on the cpu-friendly branch. Only had to change this `+opencv-python==4.3.0.38`

Comment: I get an error, despite nividia-docker being installed and verified: ERROR: for vbkgd_bodypix_1  Cannot create container for service bodypix: Unknown runtime specified nvidia

Comment: @Sephethus glad ppl are trying this out! Can you check if you are able to run a "hello world" nvidia-docker? meaning you're able to run `nvidia-smi` in the container. see https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-containers-runtime and search for "Now, let’s try running a GPU container with Docker." - just 2 lines of command, one to get you in a container and the 2nd line to check if container have gpu access.

Comment: I actually tried the other "refined" solution you linked which I got running but came across numerous other problems with it once I tried connecting zoom to it, like, it wouldn't access the camera so it was just a whitehouse press conference background. Also I got an error from your above suggestion, it wants CUDA 11 or greater, not sure how I get that onto Ubuntu 20.04. Yet if I type nvidia-smi it says I have "NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0"

Comment: maybe try redDevil's solution - using cpu only branch. If you still want to try this with GPU, I recommend posting a new question. looks like the issue is just getting your gpu accessible inside the container.

Comment: @Sephethus The CUDA version indicated by `nvidia-smi` is the driver API compatibility version, not the one installed (see https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-doesnt-show-cuda-version-even-after-installation/68738/2). To find the CUDA version installed, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9730706/2449365.

Comment: Ok so I have 10.1 installed, there is no 11 that I can find for Ubuntu...

Comment: Scratch that I got 11.1 installed but now I'm getting errors in testing like WARNING - libnvscibuf.so not found, please install libnvscibuf.so

Comment: @Sephethus I've had issues like that before trying to install CUDA. It can be tricky to fix and I think a full explanation might be a bit long for the comment section. But the thing is, I don't think you need to actually install CUDA, just the NVIDIA Container Toolkit should be enough.

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://github.com/fangfufu/Linux-Fake-Background-Webcam - this seems to be a newer, maintained version, based originally on the same code, but updated to use more efficient libraries now.

Comment: And it seems there is also now a snap packaged version of this original software. Check https://snapcraft.io/fakecam

Answer (score 13):

You have to go to: 
Settings > General > View Advanced Features > (the web site will open. log in) > Settings > In Meeting (advanced) > Enable Virtual Background.

For some reason, it is disabled by default in Ubuntu Zoom Client, and behave differently.

[image]

Then. in the Linux Client go to Settings and you will see a new submenu: Virtual Background

[image]

In previous versions (<5) a green background was required, it is no longer necessary and only a single colour background is needed, preferably green.

Hope this help.

Comment: This was not present for me in 5.1, but was after upgrading to 5.4

Comment: This isn't the question....

Answer (score 10):

As others have pointed out already, virtual background without green screen is not yet supported by zoom for Linux. There is a feature request for this in the zoom developer forum. Maybe supporting it can help making this feature a priority:

https://devforum.zoom.us/t/request-implement-virtual-backgrounds-in-linux/41558

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Zoom website](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/210707503-Virtual-Background), you need to have a physical green screen to have virtual backgrounds on Ubuntu:

> Linux Requirements
>
> - Zoom Desktop Client for Linux, version 2.0.91373.0502 or higher
> - Dual Core 2Ghz or Higher (i5/i7 or AMD equivalent) processor
> - A physical green screen

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "A physical green screen" ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this not solve the issue as at the moment I do not get any message that I should put a green screen, I do not have that option at all. So even having a physical green screen I would not be able to use this feature.

Comment: Yeah, the Windows Zoom client uses image analysis to do background replacement. However, their Linux client can only do chroma-key replacement, which means that you'll get terrible results unless you use a greenscreen. If you have an Nvidia card, you might be able to hack together a proper background replacement using open-source tools, as detailed here: https://elder.dev/posts/open-source-virtual-background. I couldn't get it working myself though, but it's interesting that it's possible. Perhaps Zoom will add this feature to the Linux client in future.

Answer (score 4):

Zoom 5.7.6 (31792.0820) (August 18, 2021) finally supports virtual background without a green screen on Linux.

Comment: I just got this update. I still have to check the "I have green screen" box and my real background still shows through. Maybe my laptop does not satisfy the minimum requirements.

Comment: @user68186 did you check the running Zoom version in the "About..." dialog? It would be odd if there's a minimum requirement that isn't met on a typical laptop. It doesn't seem to require a GPU. For Ubuntu you might have to verify that the .deb file got properly installed. Please try running `sudo apt --fix-broken install` to install any missing package dependencies. That was something I had to do after running `sudo dpkg -i zoom_amd64.deb` since that didn't complete successfully.

Comment: My Zoom > Help > about shows: Version: 5.7.6 (31792.0820). Zoom seems to work.The fix broken install didn't do anything. I will update if anything changes.

Comment: Downloading 5.7.6 not from Ubuntu Software, but from the official website did the trick, and I confirm virtual backgrounds working quite nice.

Comment: @IlyaKushlianski where did you actually download 5.7.6 from? Because I downloaded it from https://zoom.us/client/latest/zoom_amd64.deb and I confirm that it doesn't work, just as before.

Comment: for me, 5.8.0 is working, 5.7.6 was not working (ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: I'm on 5.8.6 (739) and no virtual background.

Comment: Yes it does, but sometimes, it is tricky, you have to follow this : Go to Choose Virtual Background -> First Choose "None" and then, at the bottom of the screen, choose "I have a green screen", now select the virtual background of your choice, it will work. Tested on Zoom Version: 5.9.3 (1911)

Answer (score 2):

<del>With zoom 5.5.2 from [this snap](https://github.com/ogra1/zoom-snap), on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, virtual background **without** green screen actually works.
It even works rather well.</del>

Well, that might have had to do with a particular light that particular day… I'm back to virtual background not working well