# How can I choose a background for Microsoft Teams

Tags: 18.04, video-streaming, microsoft-teams

For meetings, I need to change the background to a particular image. I could not see the  "Show background effects" feature in my ubuntu 18.04. How can we add a virtual background?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1228501/367990 includes suggestions how you can use a third party software to emulate a virtual webcam and do the body detection and background merging on the fly. This would work for Teams too.

Comment: Browse teams.com to and then you can use virtual background option.

Answer (score 8):

As of January 2022, the Teams Background Effects (change/blur) works in [Microsoft Edge for Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge). I have it running on Ubuntu 20.04.

Here's what it looks like (option highlighted in red):
[image]

**Create Teams on Edge desktop file**

You can also create .desktop file to open MS Edge with Teams. You can do this by:

1. Copy and rename existing Edge .desktop file from terminial: `cp /usr/share/applications/microsoft-edge.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/microsoft-teams-edge.desktop`
2. Edit the file: `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/microsoft-teams-edge.desktop`
3. Change `Name` entry at the top of the file and replace it with something like `Name=Teams on Edge Microsoft`
4. Find the `Exec` entry in the file and replace it with `Exec=/usr/bin/microsoft-edge-stable --profile-directory="Default" https://teams.live.com/`.
   If you use multiple MS Edge profiles, change "Default" in the above command to the profile you use for Teams (eg `--profile-directory="Profile 1"`).
5. Optional: You can also set a unique icon so that Teams on Edge looks different to the default Edge icon. Here is the [icon I created for this purpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytUPJ.png).

**Background**

This functionality update is related to [Microsoft Feature ID: 85738](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=85738). It may also work in Chromium-based browsers like Chrome or Brave. Also [see here](https://office365itpros.com/2021/09/14/teams-background-effects-available-for-web-browsers/) for more info.

Comment: I tried running Teams on MS Edge and Google Chrome on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine. As far as I can tell, Teams in browsers provides even less functionalities that the Teams app for Linux. The devices tab in settings is missing and `/testcall` is not enabled. @JayDin I am guessing that you took the screenshot while receiving a call. If not, please clarify how to access the background settings. Thank you

Comment: UPDATE: the blur background functionality is enabled both on MS Edge and on Google Chrome. Since devices cannot be configured before the beginning of a call and test calls are not enabled in Teams web app, the blurred background can only be enabled when an invite link is opened in browser, or when a call is accepted. Besides the background functionality, I've noticed that screen-sharing is slightly improved in the web app compared to Teams desktop app for Linux

Comment: @IvanP I can do a test call just by using the Meet Now button, so  I didn't need an invite link to access the settings.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I did the same. The point is that using Meet Now allows to test the background functionality, but not to test microphone and speakers...which is my main reason for making a test call in view of a meeting.

Comment: If you are still looking for a solution to blur or add background on teams linux native app, I have created a workaround solution to do so.

https://github.com/prabhakar-sivanesan/MS-Teams-background-changer

You can check this github repository and follow the instructions there.

Answer (score 6):

The feature is currently absent for Linux systems. According to [Change your background for a Teams meeting - Office Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-your-background-for-a-teams-meeting-f77a2381-443a-499d-825e-509a140f4780):

> - For now, Linux users aren't able to use this feature.

Comment: Do we have any alternative

Comment: @RCvaram Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @RCvaram there are some scripts here that add a background image directly to your webcam feed: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580276/webcam-effects-on-linux